# Android:EditText.setText() not working properly?

Tags: android

Hi 
          I Want to set Data in EditText in onActivityResult() ,I Got Result From Previous Activity, But I can't set value into my Current EditText..
Hi ,my code:

```
public class MyStuff extends Activity {
EditText messageArea;
int baseValue=200;
TextView txtCounter;
Button btnStuffOk;
Button btnStuffCancel;
ImageButton imgBrowse;
private Gallery gallery;
Bitmap myBitmap;
boolean flag=false;
int val=0;
private ArrayList<String> arrayLst=new ArrayList<String>();
protected static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;
protected static final int SELECT_URL = 2;
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
String url_data="";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mystuff);



    imgBrowse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
             startActivityForResult(
                        new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                  android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI),
                        SELECT_IMAGE);
        }
        });

     gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
     gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

     messageArea=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editArea01);


     txtCounter=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCounts);

     btnStuffOk=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStufftOk);
     btnStuffCancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStuffCancel);

   messageArea.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 


        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.toString().length()<1 ||s.toString().length()>200)
            {
                btnStuffOk.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                btnStuffOk.setEnabled(true);
            }

                txtCounter.setText(""+(baseValue-s.toString().length()));

        } 
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) { 

        } 
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 

        } 
}); 
}

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       switch (requestCode) {

           case  SELECT_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                //
                break;
            }
           case SELECT_URL:
               if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                   messageArea.setText(data.getStringExtra("url"));
                   messageArea.setText("this is a test");

                    break;
               }


       } 
    } 
}
```

`data.getStringExtra("url")` shows value .. ,but i cant assign it int Edittext...
Please help Me...

Comment: pls add some code snippet whr you getting arror and logcat o/p which displayy error

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with the information you've given us?

Comment: without looking at the code it wud be really difficult 2 predict the problem, but i can make a guess, u might be using incorrect context....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your EditText instance is available and accessible into `onActivityResult` method, then use `EditText.setText()`

Additionally, as everyone else is saying, attach some code/error to let us check where the problem is.